# modifying property of a bean with singleton scope in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scope, singleton

I have a bean with singleton scope as below:

```
public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {

    private HashMap<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();


    private void load(String check) {
        if ("abc".equalsIgnoreCase(check)) {
            config.put("key", "val");
        }
        else {
            config.put("key", "val_else");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> getConfig(String check) {
        load(check);
        return config;
    }
}
```

Then in other class, I inject MyImpl and try to use config as below:

```
  @Service
  public class Service {
    @Inject
    MyInterface impl;
    public doJob(String check){
      HashMap<String, String> config = impl.getConfig(check);
      String myValue= config.get("key");
      //some other code
    }
   }
```

If I have 100s of request/sec, and if value of **check** is **abc** for some request and and **something else** for other requests, would I still having different value in **myValue**? I tried to generalized the code as I can not share the exact code here. My question here is can we modify the property of singleton bean per request?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ThreadLocal storage (see [the example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.by/2012/05/how-to-use-threadlocal-in-java-benefits.html)) to avoid the problem.

Alternatively you can change the bean scope to be `REQUEST`